# Why are four context sensitive grammar (CSG) rules needed to represent AB -> CD?

Tags: formal-grammars, context-sensitive

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuroda_normal_form) of Kuroda normal form, it says

> A straightforward technique attributed to György Révész transforms a grammar in Kuroda's form to Chomsky's CSG: AB → CD is replaced by four context-sensitive rules AB → AZ, AZ → WZ, WZ → WD and WD → CD.

Why are four rules needed here? Aren't three rules: AB → AZ, AZ → CZ, CZ → CD enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With three steps we are not forced to complete all the steps before continuing interacting with other context around the two initial letters.

In fact, Révész himself answers this question, in his [Introduction to Formal Languages](https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToFormalLanguagesByGyorgyE.Revesz/page/n63) at archive.org, with the following example.

> Note that three rules like AB → A'B, A'B → A'D, and A'D → CD are 
>   not enough to replace the rules AB → CD. For example, if we have the 
>   rules S → AB, B → DE, AB → CD in the original grammar, then this 
>   replacement makes the derivation
>
> S ⇒ AB ⇒ A'B ⇒ A'DE ⇒ CDE
>
> possible, though CDE is not derivable in the original grammar. Such 
>   parasitical derivations are often quite difficult to avoid when we are trying 
>   to transform a grammar into an equivalent one.